# Optimize binomial distribution for large numbers without using modules

Tags: python

I made this code to simulate the odds of getting tails "m" times when you toss a coin "n" times:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n<0:
        return "Indefinido"
    if n==0 or n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        valor=1
        for i in range(2,n+1):
            valor*=i
        return valor

def binomial(n,m):
    if m>n:
        return "Indefinido"
    probabilidade=factorial(n)/(factorial(m)*factorial(n-m))*(1/2)**n
    return probabilidade
```

However this code doesn't work for (n,m) pairs such as (10000, 5000) or (100000, 50000) because these integers are too large for a float.
Is it possible to make it work for values that large without importing any modules?

I tried to optimize the code by adding a dictionary that stores some values:

```
memo = {}

def factorial(n):
    if n < 0:
        return "Indefinido"
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    if n in memo:
        return memo[n]
    else:
        resultado = n * factorial(n - 1)
        memo[n] = resultado
        return resultado

def binomial(n, m):
    if m > n:
        return "Indefinido"
    probabilidade = factorial(n) / (factorial(m) * factorial(n - m)) * (1 / 2) ** n
    return probabilidade
```

but I got the following message:

`"Windows fatal exception: stack overflow"`

Comment: Once you have numbers that large you should just use the normal approximation to the binomial. (One of the consequences of the Central Limit Theorem).

Comment: Why without modules?

Comment: In `binomial`, why return "Indefinido" instead of 0? The odds of getting more tails than coin tosses is simply 0, nothing wrong with that. And for the caller it's *much* more useful. Having to handle exceptionally getting a string is just nasty.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by calculating the binomial coefficient more carefully. Using the multiplicative formula (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula)).

```py
def binomial(n,m):
    if m>n:
        return "Indefinido"
    prod = 1
    for i in range(1, min(m, n - m) + 1):
        prod = prod * (n + 1 - i) // i
    return prod

def pdf(n, m):
    return binomial(n,m) / 2**n

pdf(10_000, 5_000) # 0.007978646139382154
```

Answer (score 0):

Your options are limited if you want to use large factorials in the classic form that is used in algebra textbooks. 170! is the upper limit before double precision variables overflow N! Anything beyond that is a Nan.

You are best off using the normal approximation to the tail of the distribution once N gets large - as suggested by @lastchance. The most obvious way for DIY would be to compute an approximate value for the log of the distribution you seek using the Stirling approximation for N! in the form:

```
log(N!) ~= N*log(N) - N + 1/2*log(2*pi*N)
```

This method will allow you to accurately represent the remote tail of the binomial distribution for any N,m without too much difficulty.

If you really don't want to include any special function math libraries, log or exp then you can always do it as the product definition. Evaluating this expression reliably requires taking great care that none of the intermediate results overflow or underflow. Getting it right for the widest possible range of N,m and p (1/2 in your case) will require some careful protection code.

```
N!/(m!*(N-m)!)*(1/2)^N = N!/(N-m)! * 1/m! * (1/2)^N

assume m<N/2 and separate the remaining m ratio terms 

(N-m+1)/1 * (N-m+2)/2 * (N-m+3)/3 * ... * N/m * (1/2)^N
```

This still isn't ideal since you have to take great care computing it to avoid underflow or overflow. Standard double precision variables computing (1/2)^N will underflow to a denormal value when N = 1024 (and to zero soon after).

It is for this reason that I think you would be better served by computing the log of the function that you seek. That can handle extreme values easily.

The other brute force option is to use a language like Julia that permits arbitrary precision arithmetic or at least extremely high precision floating point values.

Comment: You could [keep the product between 0.5 and 1](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY5NCsIwEIX3c4q3TNKE_oAgQr2Li9QOmGkplcaz6KIbvZO3sW3UtxnmzWPed3_1t7HtZJ6f17Fx-_dDLAJqlMUqi906iKKFX12LgppuAIMFw0nOXgUWFSzEBa0PhEURpoYSxxo5FGel3uyp5YtfjkeUKZeyeY3qv3pkSwttHypjlHeiifqBZVRRJ8Yv6g_5Aw), tracking the exponent of 2 separately.

Comment: Or with [small steps at the end](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY9BDoIwEEX3c4q_bKUNYGJijPUuLopMYgdCMOJZ3LDRA3gbbyO1wN9M5s_LzPznu330dSPj-Lr1ld1_P2IQ4FAWUQa7WIgGAx9dAytUNR0YLOjOcvEqsKhgIDZofSBMGrBxUGJZI4firNR_-17z1U_DE8rEJTZ32K6tRzadoYR6HFEsK1dsRqjtWHo16PT5HGAJ8gM).

Answer (score -1):

The *last* thing you should attempt to do here is calculate actual factorials; (a) they get large very quickly; (b) most of their elements will cancel. Either do the calculation by incremental multiply/divide or (possibly better, especially for a range of r values) use a normal-distribution approximation with mean np and variance npq.

The probability of r successes is <sup>n</sup>C<sub>r</sub>.p<sup>r</sup>q<sup>n-r</sup>. You can write the <sup>n</sup>C<sub>r</sub> term as

(n/r) . (n-1)/(r-1) . (n-2)/(r-2) ... (n-r+1)/1

and evaluate it by successively multiplying/dividing terms.

However, an alternative way for large numbers is to *take logs*. The numbers are relatively small and the multiplies and divides become add and subtract.

The second method is the normal approximation to the binomial. This is even better if you want a *range* of probabilities. This approximation is generally considered OK if np>5 and nq>5, especially if, as here, the distribution is symmetric.

The following code evaluates a binomial probability directly and also forms the normal approximation. Note that, for large n, individual discrete probabilities are going to be very small and a range of values of r is more realistic.

```
from math import exp, log, sqrt
from scipy.special import erf

def one_probability( n, r, p ):
    q = 1.0 - p
    logprob = 0.0
    for i in range( r ):
        logprob += log( n - i ) - log( r - i )
    logprob += r * log( p ) + ( n - r ) * log( q )
    return exp( logprob )

def normal_approximation( n, r1, r2, p ):
    mean = n * p
    sigma = sqrt( n * p * ( 1.0 - p ) )
    z1 = ( r1 - 0.5 - mean ) / sigma
    z2 = ( r2 + 0.5 - mean ) / sigma
    return 0.5  * ( erf( z2 / sqrt( 2.0 ) ) - erf( z1 / sqrt( 2.0 ) ) )


n, r, p = 10000, 5000, 0.5
print( one_probability( n, r, p ), normal_approximation( n, r, r, p ) )

n, r, p = 100000, 50000, 0.5
print( one_probability( n, r, p ), normal_approximation( n, r, r, p ) )
```

Output:

```
0.007978646139230265 0.007978712629263206
0.0025231262152840186 0.0025231283168055973
```

Answer (score -1):

Minimal fix: Replace

```
factorial(n)/(factorial(m)*factorial(n-m))*(1/2)**n
```

with:

```
factorial(n)//(factorial(m)*factorial(n-m))/2**n
```

That works with exact values as long as possible, until the final division where it necessarily becomes a float. And I think Python gives you the most accurate float possible there.

Result for your large (100000, 50000): `0.00252312621419674`

More efficient without factorials:

```
def binomial(n,m):
    m = min(m, n-m)
    if m > n:
        return "Indefinido"
    nCm = 1
    for i in range(m):
        nCm = nCm * (n-i) // (i+1)
    return nCm / 2**n
```